# Change Build Action” to “Embedded Resource in c#

Tags: c#

how to add change .dll file Build Action” to “Embedded Resource in c#.

Answer (score 12):

1. In the Solution Explorer window in Visual Studio, click on the file you want to modify.
2. In the Properties windows, change the Build Action to Embedded Resource.

Comment: Does this apply to third-party DLLs added as References to the project? I don't see any Build Action property in the Property Window of referenced files.

Comment: @Tim - Negative. This question was in regards to resources within the project, such as photos, not external references.

Answer (score 2):

Choose the resource, and right click on it and open the Properties window. 
In the Properties window, set the BuildAction to "Embedded Resource"

Answer (score 0):

Click in the solution explorer the file that will be modified. Then hit F4 or click with the right button in the file and then select the "Properties" option.
In the Properties window, change Build Action to Embedded Resource.

Answer (score 0):

**using visual studio:**

In the Properties dialog box, locate the Build Action property. By default, this property is set to Content. Click the property and change the Build Action property to Embedded Resource.

**using command prompt**

e.g. :

Compile in.cs and attach resource file rf.resource:

```
csc /resource:rf.resource in.cs
```