# Why does GetManifestResourceStream returns null while the resource name exists when calling GetManifestResourceNames?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web application project.  I generated the DLL and import it in another project.  I implemented `VirtualPathProvider`.

I followed this web site: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910441/en-us?spid=8940&sid=global, and everything works until I add another site master.

1. I added `site_export.master` and changed its Build Action to Embedded Resource.
2. I changed my page to use the new site master.
3. `GetManifestResourceStream()` returns `null` when I load `site_export.master`.
4. I call `GetManifestResourceNames()` to check if `site_export.master` exists in the DLL and it does.  It's in the list. All of the name spaces match. I didn't list the name space out here.

Why can't `GetManifestResourceStream()` load my new `site_export.master`?  It loads `site.master` just fine.  I know my DLL is loaded because I can see other files in the DLL.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't load a manifest resource with GetManifestResourceStream()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068736/cant-load-a-manifest-resource-with-getmanifestresourcestream)

Comment: Once I get one working I tend to cut, paste and edit it to create more

Answer (score 110):

Remember the following issues...

*Step 1*. Build action set to embedded resource see

[C#’s GetManifestResourceStream Gotcha](http://adrianmejia.com/blog/2011/07/18/cs-getmanifestresourcestream-gotcha)

*Step 2*. Use `namespace.resourcename` see [GetManifestResourceStream() returns null ?](http://nullfork.blogspot.com/2011/09/getmanifestresourcestream-returns-null.html)

Actually, this method returns null if a private resource in another assembly is accessed and the caller does not have `ReflectionPermission` with the `ReflectionPermissionFlag.MemberAccess` flag.

Comment: Haha... Embedded resource... Thank you very much, saved a lot of time :)

Comment: To mention that in the project properties page the Default Namespace is defined. This is the namespace to use.

Comment: If the image is in a sub-folder, use `namespace.subfolder.resourcename`.

Comment: This post explains how to do Step 1 of the above solution (set Build Action to 'Embedded resource') https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10587875/change-build-action-to-embedded-resource-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 96):

Side-hint. To make sure you're in the right assembly and with right name: dump and evaluate all the resources available in your target assembly

```
string[] names = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();
```

(in my case, I misused a namespace from another assembly)

Comment: In simple case paste this to "Immediate Window" while debugging: `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames();`

Comment: @JuhaPalomäki, it may help, but not in all cases (so you would receive something like "evaluation requires all threads to run"), especially in VS2017.

Comment: Great when you are at the exception and run it at debug :)

Comment: If it doesn't work in the immediate window you can just inspect a variable that you set in the code:
var dudes = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames();

Comment: Thank You. The issue was wrong path to the resource.

Answer (score 14):

I did this to make it work:

**Step 1:** Select the resource (CRDF.xsl in my case) and right click > Properties.
Set Build Action to "EmbeddedResource" and Logical Name to name of your choice, e.g. CRDFXSL.

**Step 2 :** Change your Source code like this:

```
Assembly _assembly;
  _assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();         
  xslStream = _assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("CRDFXSL");
  _xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(xslStream);
```

Thus everything went smoooooooth..

Comment: One thing to add - you may need to set `<LogicalName>` in *.csproj file [manually](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c94da8fd-0b0f-45c0-b137-25ab5ccc7e53/create-project-item-with-the-logicalnamelogicalname-attribute-in-the-project-file?forum=vsx).

Answer (score 4):

Hint and Caution:
If the "Assembly name" and "Default namespace" does not match in the project file then also GetManifestResourceStream would return null. GetManifestResourceNames still returns the names of assemblies but during loading the manifest would not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim ctx As Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Core.ResourceContext = New Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Core.ResourceContext()
ctx.Languages = {Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Name}
Dim rmap As Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Core.ResourceMap = Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Core.ResourceManager.Current.MainResourceMap
Dim res = rmap.GetValue("Assets/sample.png", ctx)
Dim resFile = Await res.GetValueAsFileAsync
```

The `Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Core.ResourceManager.Current.MainResourceMap` list all resources.