# Null stream when loading embedded image

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, image

I'm trying to load my company logo as an embedded image into the program, but I'm getting a null stream when I try to save it to my `logo` variable. I've looked up examples, and my code seems to be right, but it doesn't work. Is there a way I can check what all my values should be for the string in the second line? Thanks!

```
        var stream = typeof(Program).Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("[Point Of Sales.vshost.exe].[POS_System.csproj].Images.logo.bmp");
        logo = Image.FromStream(stream);
```

Comment: Perhaps you have the same issue as discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10726857/why-does-getmanifestresourcestream-returns-null-while-the-resource-name-exists-w

Comment: As an aside the process with `vshost.exe` in its name is not your program but the visual studio hosting process.

Comment: you're trying to get the image from the application resources: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192054/load-image-from-resources-area-of-project-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the namespace of the project the resource is located in, not the file name.

For example if your namespace is `MyProject.MyCode`, then your import statement should be something like:

```
var stream = typeof(Program).Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("MyProject.MyCode.Images.logo.bmp");
logo = Image.FromStream(stream);
```

For more information:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319292