# An Exception occurs when I try to assign a picture to a picturebox

Tags: c#, picturebox

I am trying to put a picture in a picturebox, but I keep getting an ArgumentException that says "Value of 'null' is not valid for 'stream'." I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
Stream myStream = myAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream("WindowsFormsApplication2.Resources.clock3.png");

Image img = Image.FromStream(myStream);
pictureBox1.Image = img;
```

Comment: I presume the exception is actually thrown on `Image.FromStream` rather than `pictureBox1.Image = img`, right?

Comment: @p.s.w.g yes you are right.

Comment: In that case I guess the resource name is wrong, because `myStream` is actually null. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10726857/why-does-getmanifestresourcestream-returns-null-while-the-resource-name-exists-w

Comment: does your image is contained  in application.resources

Comment: @p.s.w.g but i am sure that the resource name is correct

Comment: @ELF You might try calling [`GetManifestResourceNames`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getmanifestresourcenames(v=vs.110).aspx) just to verify.

Comment: @p.s.w.g it didn't work, thanks though.