# Remove prefixed namespace from embedded resource

Tags: c#, .net

How do I extract just the file name excluding the namespace using the following code? Currently this code includes the entire namespace from GetManifestResourceNames().

```
 Assembly assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(resourceLocation + @"\\" + file);


            string[] names = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();

            foreach (var name in names.Where(x => x.EndsWith("xsd")).ToList())
            {
                using (System.IO.Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(name))
                {

                    using (System.IO.FileStream fileStream = new System.IO.FileStream(System.IO.Path.Combine(outputDir, name), System.IO.FileMode.Create))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use GetManifestResourceInfo to get additional information, such as the file name.

Taking your example, you might end up with something like the following:

```
string[] names = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();

foreach (var name in names.Where(x => x.EndsWith("xsd")).ToList())
{
    var info = assembly.GetManifestResourceInfo(name);
    if (info != null)
    {
        var fileName = info.FileName;
        // Do your stuff that needs filename here.
    }

}
```

EDIT: This SO post might be relevant, if you find GetManifestResourceInfo returning null in these cases: [Why does GetManifestResourceStream returns null while the resource name exists when calling GetManifestResourceNames?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10726857/why-does-getmanifestresourcestream-returns-null-while-the-resource-name-exists-w)

The resources should be set to build action of "Embedded Resource", and there is the code security gotcha that is mentioned here: http://adrianmejia.com/blog/2011/07/18/cs-getmanifestresourcestream-gotcha/

Comment: For some reason GetManifestResourceInfo always returns null. Or at least the FileName

Comment: Hm, is the "Build Action" on the resources is set to "Embedded Resource"?

Comment: Also, see this I think it's quite relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10726857/why-does-getmanifestresourcestream-returns-null-while-the-resource-name-exists-w

Comment: Yeah the Build Action is set to Embedded resource because I can save the XSD with the full namespace & file name .xsd.

Comment: Could it be the code security issue I linked to in my edited post?

Comment: It could be. I tried setting the <LogicalName></LogicalName> in the csproj file and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Other than some hackey and brittle solution like regexing the full name, I think I'm out of helpful suggestions.  Perhaps it would be worthwhile to spool this up as a separate SO question, about why GetManifestResourceInfo is returning null for you.  If it's none of the reasons mentioned in the linked posts, then it probably warrants its own.

Comment: Turns out it was a MSI configuration issue was the reason FileName was null.