# Why does GetManifestResourceStream fail at runtime?

Tags: c#, servicestack, embedded-resource, aspose-cells

I am running into a hard to reproduce bug in production code where I am seeing `GetManifestResourceStream` return `null` at runtime.

Context: I am running a Service Stack service self hosted as a Windows Service. This service wraps 3rd party software that requires a license file. I have added the license file to the project and configured it as an `Embedded Resource`.

The license is loaded per request in the following way:

```
var license = new License();
using (var licStream = EmbeddedResourceScope.GetStream(Constants.LicenseFile))
{
    // licStream can sometimes be null at runtime
    license.SetLicense(licStream);
}
```

Here is the code for `EmbeddedResourceScope`

```
public static class EmbeddedResourceScope
{
    public static Stream GetStream(EmbeddedResource name)
    {
        var scope = typeof (EmbeddedResourceScope);
        var resourceAssembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(scope);
        var resourceStream = resourceAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(scope, name);

        return resourceStream;
    }
}
```

Am I missing something obvious here? Maybe related to thread safety?

When the runtime issue pops up, this code fails for every request until the service is restarted.

Comment: Can you check whether the license file has been correctly added as an embedded resource? Please share what `this.GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();` returns if called from your assembly in which the license file resides. Also please make sure that `Constants.LicenseFile` is not only the file name alone, but e.g. `MyProject.LicenseFile.txt` (note the `MyProject,` at the beginning).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does GetManifestResourceStream returns null while the resource name exists when calling GetManifestResourceNames?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10726857/why-does-getmanifestresourcestream-returns-null-while-the-resource-name-exists-w)